# Backgroung set in stylesheet is seen with script.py but not after converting it to script.exe with pyinstaller

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

The background is set in the script as follows:

```
stylesheet = """
QMainWindow {
border-image: url(image.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
"""
```

and later in

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app1 = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app1.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)  # <---
    window = EncryptPDF()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app1.exec_())
```

It works ok while used in the python script, but after converting to an executable with pyinstaller, the background image is not shown.
Any suggestions on how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you include the image in the package? Besides, the syntax is not really correct.

Comment: How should I include an image, by using --add-data? If that's what you meant, than yes, I tried adding the --add-data flag and got the same result. I also tried the --add-binary flag to no avail. What's wrong with the syntax? It works when run as a python script.

Comment: but *how* did you used those flags? Is the file actually added? Is the relative path used correctly in respect to the working dir?

Comment: Oh. The PNG file and and script are in the same path, and the command runs in the common directory. The last command I used was `pyinstaller --onefile --clean --windowed --add-data "*.png;." file_1.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this same problem before as well.

In PyQt5 when setting that css using url(), the code is looking for your image.png the directory you give it, if there is no path then it looks in the same directory as the python script. When the python script is converted to an .exe that directory changes.

What I do for my scripts is:
I decide if the code is running as an exe or a python script by checking if sys has an attribute called "frozen" which is present when pyinstaller converts it to an .exe.
If I know it's an exe, I then instead switch my base path to the path of my executable file, which should be put in the same place as your main python file in the directory.

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    EXE_APPLICATION = True
elif __file__:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    EXE_APPLICATION = False
```

The code above is something I include in any python script I intend to convert to an exe. Throughout my project I will reference other files using something like:

```
image_path = os.path.join(application_path, "image.png")

stylesheet = """
QMainWindow {
border-image: url(image_path) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
"""
```

EDIT:

If your project includes multiprocessing don't forget to include

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

This will make sure the multiprocessing works as an .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Was the image included as part of the data during the conversion? you can check by launching the executable through command line (not double-clicking it), you may be able to find more information from the error message.

if the image is in fact missing, you could add through the command line by using the argument `--add-data "image.png"` or include it in the .spec file: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There was no error message. I tried using --add-data and --add-binary and both commands worked, meaning, they didn't fail, but the resulting executable launched the program without the background image as before.